# My EC2 Linux Failing to connect to awscli.amazonaws.com:443

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

My Linux EC2 Instance comes up under VPC --> subnet with proper route table having Internet gateway (0.0.0.0/0 as destination).
It comes up with Private IPv4 address assigned to it, no Public IPv4.
Attached the related Security group and NACL screenshot.

[Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8p0v.png)

[NACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTbvp.png)

Under Security Group, I have opened:

- HTTPS (443) to 0.0.0.0/0,
- ssh (22) to my machine IP and my VPC CIDR range.

After I ssh into my EC2 instance using the Private IPv4 address and keys, I've been trying to add AWS cli to my instance

My ec2 instance produces this after I enter this:

```
curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.0.30.zip -o awscliv2.zip
```

Error:

> 0curl: (7) Failed connect to awscli.amazonaws.com:443;

Where is the problem?

Comment: @Felix: the OP appears to be trying to download the AWS console installer. I ran their exact command on my local machine and received a binary file: `100 31.5M  100 31.5M    0     0  4392k      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:-- 5852k`.

Comment: Thus Felix, I wonder if you might make your tone a little kinder. You made a mistake on this occasion, and I suspect the guidance you might give here is that there is a firewall issue and/or how the networking issue can be traced.

Comment: Suman, the host you are trying to reach resolves (at least for me) to `143.204.89.92`. Can you try pinging that from your EC2 instance?

Comment: sorry everybody - I removed my comment. However, repost.aws is still a better place to ask such question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instance is in the private subnet and has no public IP, you can't route through Internet Gateway. You have to route through some NAT device. The simplest is [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), although you can also set up an EC2 instance to serve same purpose.

When you set up a new VPC using (recently added) wizard, it offers you an option to create public and private subnets and NAT Gateway automatically. Or you can add it to an existing VPC following [these](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/) instructions.

Note, that unlike Internet Gateway, NAT Gateway is not free

PS. Sorry again for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. It worked. I created a NAT gateway with an Elastic IP address under a public subnet. And routed my private subnet to use this NAT gateway. My EC2 instance under this private subnet was able to access the Internet afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your instance has any firewall running? You can disable the firewalls (if any) using these commands :

```
# For Uncomplicated Firewall
sudo ufw disable

# For firewalld
sudo systemctl disable firewalld --now
```

Also, the official documentation for aws cli installation has double quotes surrounding the https address (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html)

`curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"`

This may or may not be the issue but its worth a try.